# Using ligatures in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, spyder, figure

Is there a way to get matplotlib (in Spyder or otherwise) to support ligatures?

My end goal is to create mpl style sheets so I don't need to constantly update the rcParams when switching from one work to another (e.g. wanting a display-weighted sans serif font for a poster, but a caption-weighted serif font for a paper).

MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path

fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3),dpi=600)
fpath=Path("C:\Windows\Fonts\GaramondPremrPro.otf")
ax.set_title(f'{fpath.name}', font=fpath, fontsize=15)
ax.set_xlabel('Default matplotlib font', fontsize=15)

ax.annotate(
   'Th fi fl ft',
   xy=(0.2,0.45),
   textcoords='data',
   font=fpath,
   fontsize=30)

plt.show()
fig.savefig(r'C:Pictures\garamond.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

This is [the resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weKiT.png), and this is [a reference photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4v7P.png) for how the ligatures *should* look.

I'd appreciate suggestions that could be adapted to both one-off figures, and also permanent style sheets. Thanks!

Comment: For ligatures you can probably use latex. https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/usetex.html

Comment: Funnily enough, adding usetex actually makes things worse, at least without further steps that are not obvious. The first thing that '"text.usetex": True' does is make a typographical abomination, since the numbers on the axes are in Computer Modern, but the main text is in DejaVu Sans; this also overwrites the font modifications I made in my MWE. You can specify using a particular font (Palatino, Helvetica) that is **built in** to matplotlib, but not any other (better) fonts.

Comment: Matplotlib text engine does not, so far as I know, try to identify ligatures.  Latex does.  If you want to use nonstandard fonts in latex, you can install and change the preamble to have \usepackage{myawesomefonts}.

Answer (score 0):

You could create objects that own the different style sheets and then import the corresponding one or ones into your current work as needed. The class could also potentially change matplotlib default settings as well if that is handy.

```py
class StyleSheetPaper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fpath = <...>
        self.font = <...>

...
```

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path
from stylesheets import StyleSheetPaper, StyleSheetPoster


styler = StyleSheetPaper()

fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3),dpi=600)
ax.set_title(f'{styler.fpath.name}', font=styler.fpath, fontsize=15)
ax.set_xlabel('Default matplotlib font', fontsize=15)

ax.annotate(
   'Th fi fl ft',
   xy=(0.2,0.45),
   textcoords='data',
   font=styler.fpath,
   fontsize=30)

plt.show()
fig.savefig(r'C:Pictures\garamond.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```